# Having an 'update' button issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a strange issue which I don't really understand. I have created a registration/login page and on the registration page it asks for your full name, email, and gender. And once you've logged in there is a button for 'My Details', once you click that you can change your details. So here is my issue, when I click 'My Details' I can see the full name, email and gender. But when I try to update it, it just clears even though it states 'Successfully updated' it will be wiped completely and even the old details will be removed. I suspect its the following code..

```
<?php
//this authenticates user
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>

<?php include ('header.php'); ?> 

<?php
$update = (isset($_GET['update']) ? $_GET['update'] : null);
$full_name = (isset($_GET['full_name']) ? $_GET['full_name'] : null);
$full_name = strip_tags($full_name);
$location = (isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET['location'] : null);
$location = strip_tags($location);
$gender = (isset($_GET['gender']) ? $_GET['gender'] : null);

if($update == 1 && !empty($_POST)) // Checks if the form is submitted or not
{
$success_update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET fullname='$full_name', location='$location', gender='$gender' WHERE username='$username' ");
if($success_update) { 
echo '
<div class="alert alert-success">
Account Successfully updated!
</div>
';
} 

else {
echo '
<div class="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
Failed to update
</div>
';


}

}

$document_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$match_value = mysql_fetch_array($document_get);
$fullname = $match_value['fullname'];
$location = $match_value['location'];
$gender = $match_value['gender'];

?>
<br/>

 <div style="float:right"> <a class="btn btn-info" href="dashboard.php" > Account </a>  <a class="btn" href="home.php"> <i class="icon-home icon-black"></i>Home</a> 
 <a class="btn btn-danger logout" href="logout.php" > Logout</a> 

 </div>

 <fieldset>
    <legend>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>, </legend>

    <br/>
    <br/>
<form action="settings.php?update=1" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Settings</legend>

    <label>Full Name *</label>
    <input name="full_name" type="text" placeholder="Type something…" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" >
    <br/>
    <label>Location </label>
    <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Type something…" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">
    <br/>
    <label>Gender </label>
    <select name="gender">
  <option <?php if($gender == 'Male') echo 'selected'; ?> >Male</option>
  <option <?php if($gender == 'Female') echo 'selected'; ?> >Female</option>
</select>

    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Update</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
 </fieldset>





 <script>

 function validate()
{


   if( document.myForm.full_name.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your full name!" );
     document.myForm.full_name.focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   return( true );
}


 $('.logout').click(function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to Logout?");
})
</script>
<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

Any idea? Cheers

Comment: Are you sure it's a `$_GET` and not a `$_POST`, resulting in your variables being `null`, thus updating all fields to `null`?

Comment: Hi, My name is `bobby'; drop table users; --`, but when I try to sign up your site crashes and breaks for everyone. Have you considered escaping input so people can't delete your tables by entering SQL Injection attacks?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @scragar I don't plan on putting my site live.

Comment: @Ellie don't go lazy on security, even if it isn't live.

Comment: Try to echo query. $query = "UPDATE users SET fullname='$full_name', location='$location', gender='$gender' WHERE username='$username' "; $success_update = mysql_query($query); echo $query; and try to execute this query directly on server via some mysql manager.

Comment: Try this after your $gender=... line to make sure your variables are defined: echo("<br>Variable contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r(get_defined_vars(), 1) . "</pre>"); exit;

Comment: @rrtx2000 
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
            [PHPSESSID] => esqsclptpmosio9151tujfh1p3
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    [_SESSION] => Array
        (
            [username] => admin
        )

    [username] => admin
    
    [connection] => Resource id #5
    [database] => 1
    [update] => 
    [full_name] => 
    [location] => 
    [gender] => 
Variable contents:
)

Comment: Your username is set but your full_name, location and gender are blank. Try these: 
echo("<br><br>Get contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r($_GET, 1) . "</pre>");
echo("<br>Post contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r($_POST, 1) . "</pre>");

Comment: @rrtx2000 Gave me an error when trying to do so.

Comment: I use them all the time. I just copy and pasted them from some of my code. Look out for pasting errors such as missing semicolons.

Comment: echo("<br><br>Get contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r($_GET, 1) . "</pre>");
echo("<br>Post contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r($_POST, 1) . "</pre>");

Comment: @rrtx2000 Unexpected echo

Comment: Make sure you're not missing a semicolon before my code.

Comment: @rrtx2000 Get contents:
Array
(
)

Post contents:
Array
(
)

Comment: There you have it. The page before this one isn't posting anything to it.

Comment: @rrtx2000  What do you suggest I change in this code.......................  <?php
$document_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$match_value = mysql_fetch_array($document_get);
$fullname = $match_value['fullname'];
$location = $match_value['location'];
$gender = $match_value['gender']; 
?> << THE OTHER PAGE

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure it's a `$_GET` and not a `$_POST`, resulting in your variables being null, thus updating all fields to null?
- `$username` isn't being declared
- You're vulnerable to SQL injection

From your code, you check for `$_POST`, so I assume you mean to check for `$_POST` and not `$_GET` at the top of your file.

Replace the top part of your file with;

```
$update = (isset($_POST['update']) ? $_POST['update'] : null);
$username = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null);
$full_name = (isset($_POST['full_name']) ? $_POST['full_name'] : null);
$full_name = strip_tags($full_name);
$location = (isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : null);
$location = strip_tags($location);
$gender = (isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : null);
```

Also, please take action regarding @esqew comment;

> Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use PDO or MySQLi - this article will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I've just updated it to declare `$username`. It would be wise to put your query into a variable and `echo` it out, so we can further debug. (Also, `print_r(mysql_error($success_update))`)

Comment: I've updated as you can see my edited post above and still isn't seeming to work :(